# How can I combine this two arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am facing a problem with php, and I've tried so hard to make it work but I guess I need some help.

This is my problem:

I receive weekly a csv to update the stock amount in a client online shop, and I am trying to make it easier by uploading a csv and it updates the stock.

Problem is in DB the stock table is linked to product ID and not the name ( which makes sense).

The website has multiple vendors and all of them share the same products and the same stock amount.

When I upload the file, I get 2 arrays, array1 has all the product names array2 has the stock amount of each. Just like in my csv file
Example:

```
Array1 = ['Product1','Product2','Product3']; //products
Array2 = ['1','3','7']; // stock amount
```

My next step is to make a query to get the IDS from all vendors of each product in array1

Now I have something like this

```
Array3 = array('1', '14' , '25' )  , array ('2', '15' , '26' ) , array('3', '16' , '27' ); //
```

Now the struggle comes, how can I associate the stock to those Id's?

I need to associate ID's 1,14,25 to 1 stock amount , 2,15,26  to 3 stock amount and 3,16,27 to 7 stock amount.

Comment: What would be an example of the SQL to update for the example `ID's 1,14,25 to 1 stock amount`?

Comment: Please share more details - what's the result you expect? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Did you give up?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over both arrays and use them to build a new one. Something like this:

```
$Array3 = array();

for($i = 0; $i < count($Array1); $i++) {
   $Array3[$Array1[$i]] = $Array2[$i];
}
```

This creates an associated Array3 where the keys are the values from Array1 and the values are the values from Array2, linked by their position in the original arrays.

This *might* work for you, but you should check if the length is the same and much more...

Comment: Please note that this is not PHP syntax.

Comment: You're right, did too much JS the last days. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Your overall approach is probably not the best but it's hard to tell.  However, with what you have, if you combine the arrays with keys and values then you can loop and use them:

```
foreach(array_combine($Array2, $Array3) as $stock => $ids) {
    $ids = implode(',', $ids);
    //UPDATE tablename SET stock_amount=$stock WHERE vendor_id IN($ids)
}
```

Not sure what you're trying to do with the arrays so that's just an example how to relate them based on order.